# Google script: use html file from imported project

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I want to keep common resources, such as css and js, in a common google script project and then import them in different projects (web apps)

So, instead of using a local file:

```
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('CSS').getContent(); ?>
```

I want to use an asset from an imported file (Resources > libraries > import project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your library, you need both the shared HTML files as well as functions that will return their content. You can then call those functions in your projects.

#### Library

Code.gs:

```
/**
 * Gets the CSS file as HTML and returns its content.
 * @returns {string}
 */
function getCss() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("CSS").getContent();
}
```

CSS.html

```
<style>
  p {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
</style>
```

---

#### Project

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index").evaluate();
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= Library.getCss(); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </body>
</html>
```